# DataTable with 2 TR not showing pagination, search, sorting

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4, datatable

I am using DataTable and accordian collapse to display data in a table and upon click of 'Click to View' in first tr, the div in second tr expands to display data. Around 25 records are being fetched from DB. Now issue being faced is that pagination, sorting, show [10] entries, search box not showing up at all and all data are being displayed at once. What changes to I need to do make it work as usual? Below is the structure with 2 tr.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed dataTable" id="odata">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
        <th>D</th>
        <th>E</th>
        <th>F</th>
        <th>G</th>
        <th>H</th>
        <th>View</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody >
<!------------ Inside For Loop - Start -------------------->
    <tr id="1">
        <td>1.</td>
        <td>A from DB</td>
        <td>B from DB</td>
        <td>C from DB</td>
        <td>D from DB</td>
        <td>E from DB</td>
        <td>F from DB</td>
        <td>G from DB</td>
        <td>H from DB</td>
        <td class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="demo_x">Click to View</td> <!------------ x changes with for loop index ----------->
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="12" class="hiddenRow" style="border-top: 0;"><div id="demo_x" class="accordian-body collapse"> <!------------ x changes with for loop index ----------->
            <div class="invoice p-3 mb-0">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
            </div>
            <!-- /.col -->
            </div>
            <!--------- Some content from DB ------->
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
<!------------ Inside For Loop - End -------------------->
</tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#odata').DataTable({
          "paging": true,
          "lengthChange": true,
          "searching": true,
          "ordering": true,
          "info": true,
          "autoWidth": false,
          "responsive": true
          
      });
```

Comment: did you add datatable css and scripts on the page?

Comment: Yes. I have. I am using datatables in other pages also in which only 1 TR has been used and results are as expected.

Comment: See the ["HTML" section of the installation](https://datatables.net/manual/installation#HTML) page: _"while DataTables supports colspan and rowspan in the table's header and footer, they are not supported in the table's tbody and must not be present."_.

Comment: If you describe why you want to use a `colspan` in your table's body, maybe we can suggest an alternative. (Also, just for future reference, the `colspan="12"` value does not match the count of 10 columns in the first row - not that it matters here.)

Comment: If I don't put the colspan then the expansion is just below first column of the above / parent tr. Basically I am try datatable with collapse. First row will contain some primary data and next row which is hidden will contain secondary data. And on click on view, second row will expand.